# The set of bilinear forms is a right $(R \otimes R)$-module

Tags: modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $V$ and $A$ be abelian groups. An $A$-valued bilinear form on $V$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism $$\beta : V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V \rightarrow A$$ Now, let $V$ be a left $R$-module, where $R$ is not necessarily commutative.

Then, the set of all $A$-valued bilinear forms is a right $(R \otimes R)$-module with the action $$\beta(r \otimes s)(x,y) = \beta(rx,sy)$$ for all $r,s \in R, x,y \in V$.

I'm struggling to see how this is true? How does $\beta(rx,sy)$ even make sense? Isn't $\beta$ just defined on the abelian group $V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V$? How is it then taking values in $V \times V$? Is this $\beta$ supposed to denote the bilinear map $V \times V \rightarrow A$ corresponding to the homomorphism $\beta: V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V \rightarrow A$ by the universal property of the tensor product? If so, how would one prove that the set of these is a right $(R \otimes R)$-module?

Comment: Do you mean $\beta(r \otimes s)(x,y) = \beta(rx,sy)$? Or maybe  $\beta(r \otimes s)(x,y) = \beta(rx\otimes sy)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, sorry, I've fixed it now thank you!

Comment: "How does $\beta(rs, sy)$ even make sense?". $\beta$ is a bilinear form. $\beta \cdot (r \otimes s)$ is a new bilinear form, i.e. a homomorphism $V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V \rightarrow A$. The formula is $(\beta \cdot ( r \otimes s)) (x \otimes y) = \beta( (rs) \otimes (sy))$. The RHS is defined, as $\beta$ was already given.

Comment: Ok, so do they just write $\beta(rs,ry)$ for $\beta((rs) \otimes (ry))$? Is this not an abuse of notation?

Comment: @theman I'm not entirely sure why they wrote $\beta(rs, ry)$, but definitely $\beta((rs) \otimes (sy))$ is correct. $\beta(rs, ry)$ is either a typo or a convention I've never heard of. Also, take a look at how this source defined $\beta$ initially. Most often, maps out of a tensor product are defined as coming from bilinear maps. Maybe they defined $\beta$ as a bilinear map initially, and never bothered to rename the map out of the tensor product that it induces (like you say, that would be abuse of notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer, I explain how $(\beta \cdot (a \otimes b))(x \otimes y) = \beta( (ax) \otimes (by))$ makes sense. Those are equalities (1) and (2) below.

---

First I want to isolate two claims we will use. These are things we should sort out first if we want to answer the question. For the following two claims, I want to emphasize that I am not using the context of your question (I use the letters differently).

> **Claim 1:** If $M$ is a left $A$-module and $N$ is a left $B$-module, then $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$ is a left $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B$ module.

We want to set $(a \otimes b) \cdot (m \otimes n) = am \otimes bn$.

$$\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}} ((A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N), M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}} ((A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M )\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N), M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$$
This isomorphism comes from the isomorphism $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N) \cong (A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M )\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$, which in turn comes from the commutativity of the tensor product. If $\alpha:  A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M \rightarrow M$ is the structure map for $M$, and $\beta : B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N \rightarrow N$ is the structure map for $N$, then $\alpha \otimes \beta$ is a map  from $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M ) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$ to $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$, and by the isomorphism above, it induces a map from $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$ to $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$.

Another way to word it is this: Let $\alpha : A \rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}} (M)$ and $\beta : B \rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M)$ be the structure maps. To define a map $\mu: A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B \rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$, send $a \otimes b$ to the map $\alpha(a) \otimes \alpha(b) : M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N \rightarrow M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N$. For $a, a' \in A$ and $b, b' \in B$, $\mu(a a' \otimes b b') = \mu(a \otimes b) \circ \mu(a' \otimes b')$.

Both of these constructions result in a multiplication such that $(a \otimes b) \cdot (m \otimes n) = am \otimes bn$. Of course, it's the same multiplication both times.

> **Claim 2:** If $X$ is a left $A$-module, and a right $B$-module, and $Y$ is a right $B$-module, then $\text{Hom}_{\text{right-} B \text{-mod}}(X,Y)$ is a right $A$-module (note this is reverse from $X$; $X$ is a left $A$-module).

We put $(\phi \cdot a)(x) = \phi(ax)$.

---

Combining these, let's see what we have in your situation. Now I work in the context of your question. $V$ and $A$ are abelian groups. Since $V$ is a left $R$-module, $V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V$ is a left $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$-module by (1). So $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V, A)$ is a right $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$-module by (2).

Let's calculate what this $R$-module structure on this abelian group. Take $\beta \in \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V, A)$, and take $r \otimes s \in R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$. What is $\beta \cdot (r \otimes s)$?

$$(\beta \cdot (r \otimes s)) (v \otimes w) \stackrel{(1)}{=} \beta (r \otimes s \cdot v \otimes w) \stackrel{(2)}{=} \beta ( (rv) \otimes (sw)) $$

This gives a formula for $\beta \cdot (r \otimes s)$ in terms of $\beta$, $r$ and $s$. The first equality holds by how we defined the $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$-module structure on $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V, A)$. The second equality holds because of how we defined the $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$-module structure on $V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} V$.

Comment: Where does the isomorphism come from in claim 1?

Comment: Also, in  the statement of claim 2, do you mean a right $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$ module?

Comment: In claim 1, the isomorphism comes from the property of tensor product that $M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N \cong N \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M$. Claim $2$ is phrased independently of the context in your question. It is the way we endow hom-sets with module structure. I don't intend to say it is a $R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} R$-module, just an $R$ module ($R$ is now changed to $A$). To make it less confusing, I will change the variables from the ones you used.

Comment: Let me know if this helped, or if you have remaining questions, e.g. about the details in these constructions.

Comment: Why does $(A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N) \cong (A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)$ imply that $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}((A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} B) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N), M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N) \cong Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}((A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} M) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} (B \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N), M \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} N)?$

Comment: Also, what is meant by the structure map?

Comment: If $X \cong Y$ are $A$-modules, and $Z$ is another $A$-module, then $\text{Hom}(X, Z) \cong \text{Hom}(Y, Z)$. You can check that by taking inverse maps $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow X$ and applying $\text{Hom}(-, Z)$. The structure map of an $A$-module $X$ is the map that induces the multiplication on it, so that would be either the map $A \rightarrow \text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(X)$ sending $a$ to $\mu_a$, where $\mu_a$ sends $x$ to $ax$, or the map $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} X \rightarrow X$ sending $a \otimes x$ to $ax$.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for your help. Do you know of anywhere where I can get a reference to this proof in the literature? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean the original question, or my last comment?

Comment: The original question, sorry.

Comment: @theman Have you tried Keith Conrad's notes? Try the last section. I don't think it explains this proof exactly, but it contains the things you would have to know to show this. If that won't do, then get back to me if you need something else.  https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/bilinearform.pdf

Comment: Another point: many of the questions you are asking pertain to general module theory and the use of the tensor product. It might not be a bad idea to familiarize yourself with that some more. I suspect that if you become more acquanted with e.g. https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod.pdf and https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf then this question will become easier or even routine for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help!